# Datatables of laravel

Tags: datatables

I'm using Laravel recently and still have some difficulty using the APIs that it makes available.
I'm working on a project and I'm using infyom for the backoffice part and the php version is 7.1.

I started with the clone of the git repository (infyom adminLTE), then I configured my .env file, created the necessary migrations and sent the php artisan migrate command. So far all right!

Now I should use YAJRA to build datatables and their CRUD operations.
Following the instructions that make GitHub available, I can not get anything.

The steps I have followed are:

1. `compiler require yajra / laravel-datatables-oracle: "~ 6.0"` // here i tried also with version 8 (but nothing)
2. 'providers' => [
       ...,
       Yajra \ DataTables \ DataTablesServiceProvider :: class,
   ]

   'aliases' => [
       ...,
       'DataTables' => Yajra \ DataTables \ Facades \ DataTables :: class,
   ]

3.`php artisan vendor: publish --provider = Yajra \ DataTables \ 
       DataTablesServiceProvide`

4. `php artisan infyom: scaffold $ MODEL_NAME --fromTable --tableName = $ TABLE_NAME`

Now my table appears in the left menu, but when I go to click it returns this type of error:

```
FatalThrowableError
Class 'Yajra \ DataTables \ DataTablesServiceProvider' not found
in ProviderRepository.php (line 208)
```

Can you tell me if I skipped a few passes?
Are the versions of these things good?